# Java Swing - Globally Change Panels to Have Pink Background

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, look-and-feel, uimanager

I know that you can change the overall look and feel of an application by setting the "look and Feel".  Is there a way to globally change components without writing a look and feel class?  For example if you wanted all of your buttons to be black how would you do this?  I'm drawing a blank.

Thanks
ST

Answer (score 4):

Use the UIManager and change the defaults for your look and feel.  There is a nice tool here: http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/10/09/uimanager-defaults/ that if you run the Java Web Start program it will allow you to browse the keys and values for each component.

However, just changing the background might cause some new issues, take a look at this question:
[Java- Changing swing background colour?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/200106/java-changing-swing-background-colour)

Answer (score 1):

One solution can be, factory pattern;

You can create a Factory class that creates buttons with predefined settings. Everytime you 
need a button use this factory class and you will get objects with predefined properties.

```
Button button = factory.createButton()

class Factory{
 Button createButton(){
   Button button = new Button();
   button.setBackgroundColor(Color.PINK);
   return  button;
 }
}
```

Comment: Thanks.  I wasn't clear.  If I have an existing application and my client said they would like a different color scheme for buttons.  How could that be accomplished?

Comment: You can extend the button class with same name like ; Button extends javax.swing.Button  and set the background value in constructor of this new class. However, you will still need to update your code and replace all javax.swing.Button imports to your new class. Easier refactorization comparing to the factory way for an existing code.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a collection of the corresponding components you could loop through them setting the BG color.

```
public void setBgColor( Color color, List< Component > components ) {
    for ( Component c : components ) {
        c.setBackgroundColor( color );
    }
}
```

The hard part is getting a list of components.  I've done this by registering certain component groups with a collection and using the above method to set various properties.  This scenario is a good argument for centralized object creation.

Answer (score -1):

What if not only the colour needs to be changed? If this is an application where everything is under your control then it makes sense to utilise inheritance -- create base classes for all required components (e.g. panels, buttons) and override the paintComponent method to suite your needs. This approach could be more modular if the behaviour of the paintComponent method in the base components could be customised at instantiation time by providing relevant "painters", which are invoked from the paintComponent method.

[Here](http://java.sun.com/products/jfc/tsc/articles/swing2d/index.html) is a potentially useful link.